# iFrame in Chrome Extension loads everytime the extension is clicked

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an iframe in my extension. The iFrame helps the user to log in the account. 
Once the user gets logged in and clicks the extension again after closing. The iframe is loaded once again and the user is logged out.

Currently the iframe is directly embedded inside the html. I also tried by appending it using JS, but even that didn't helped.

**EDIT:**
My manifest :

```
"permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*","activeTab"],
  "content_scripts":[
    {
        "matches":["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "js":["data/js/popup.js","data/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"]
    }
  ],
```

The popup.html:

```
    <div class="frame">
        <iframe id="Receiver" width="100%" height="250px" frameborder="0" src="http://abc.url/login"></iframe>
    </div>
```

The link(iframe) has login page and lets the user login into his account. I don't have any direct access to that login page, but if something is required let me know.

Issues:
1) Clicking on the extension takes a lot of time to show the popup.html : When searched a lot, I got to know that until the iframe is fully loaded the extension doesnt popup's the panel.
2) When a user logs into his account, and visits another page or closes the extension by clicking somewhere else on the browser. And then again clicks on the extension, the extension again loads the frame/takes a lot of time show the html page, and also the user is logged out.

I want something like **GroupDocs Viewer** extension in which once the user is logged in, until he presses 'logout', he is not logged out.

Comment: What is the problem again ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem : The iframe loads everytime the extension is clicked, so the user gets logged out.

Comment: You seriously need to give more details. E.g. what does "loads" mean ? Where is it loaded ? What is "clicked" ? What does the iframe do (i.e. how does it "help the user to log in the account") ? What does this sentence mean: "Once the user gets logged in and clicks the extension again after closing." ? What is your extensions sructure (background page ? content scripts ? popup ? other views ?) ? What does your manifest look like ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem :I'm editing the code once again..and sorry for the problems occuring as this is the first time I'm asking, so have no idea on what should I post.

Comment: I am really sorry, but I still do not quite understand what is going on. What does `popup.js` does (and why is it injected into any web-page) ? Is the user logged in automatically (or does (s)he have to type something in (e.g. username/password) ? Is there anything else on the `popup.html` or just the iframe ? If only the iframe then why even show a popup ? (Maybe it might be a better idea to take a step back and explain in detail what you are trying to achieve (e.g. "I want to build an extension that when the user ... then ... etc).)

Comment: @ExpertSystem : the 'popup.html' has only iframe and nothing else. The user has an id and password for logging in. 'popup.js' passes the currentUrl to the iFrame.  
I'm building an extension in which user logs into his account using his company's account and can view his assets. There is an 'Add to Favorite' button in the iframe which adds the active tab's URL in his favorites section.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, loading `http://abc.url/login` logs the user out if they are alreay logged in. So every time the popup is opened,the iframe is loaded and the user is effectively logged out.

Possible solutions:

1. Try to detect if the user is already logged in and only then add the iframe to the DOM (via JS). E.g. if there is a page that can only be accessed by a logged in user (say `http://abc.url/account`) try to access this page and see if you get an error. (The exact setup depends on the way an unauthorized request is handled by the server.)
2. Do not load the iframe by default, but have a link or button that the user has to click in order to bring up the log-in iframe.

Comment: ok. The 2nd solution is not possible..but I'll try the 1st one. :) Thanks

Comment: @IgnatiuzVinayak: If you think this answer is useful and addresses your problem, please **[mark it as "accepted"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)**, so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to spot it easily.

Comment: none of the solutions solved my problem. I'm still facing the same issue.

Comment: @IgnatiuzVinayak: Posting what you have tried (and how it fails) may help propose a solution that actually solves the problem. BTW, do you have administrative access to `http://abc.url` or is it a foreign URL ?

Comment: @IgnatiuzVinayak: I see. In any case, I can't help further if I don't provide more info. E.g. sharing your code (and explaining what you have tried and how it fails) or at least sharing what the actusl URL is.